# Converting IEnumerable<X> to IEnumerable<Y>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mapping

```
IEnumerable<ContactPerson> results = _contactPersonRepository.GetContactPersons().Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = results...
```

How can I do this? I have `IEnumerable<X>` and then I want to convert it in `IEnumerable<Y>`.

Is there any way to do this?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) (if you want project Y to new type X) or [Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) (if Y is inherited from X) extensions of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = 
    results.Select(p => CreateContactPersonViewModelFrom(p));
```

If ContactPersonViewModel is ContactPerson:

```
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = 
    results.Cast<ContactPersonViewModel>();
```

---

Usually creating view model involves manual properties mapping from entity to view model. Like this:

```
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = 
    results.Select(p => new ContactPersonViewModel {
                       Name = p.Name,
                       Phone = p.Phone
                   });
```

So I also suggest you to take look on some mapping framework like [Automapper](http://automapper.org/). It makes lot of mappings for you. And this code will look like:

```
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = 
    Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel>>(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `Enumerable.Select`:

```
var contactPersons = results.Select(r => new ContactPersonViewModel(r));
```

This assumes there's a `ContactPersonViewModel` constructor that takes a `ContactPerson`; if not, you will have to supply another way to initialize the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Try to cast it.

```
 IEnumerable<ContactPerson> results = _contactPersonRepository.GetContactPersons().Where(x => x.UserId == user.UserId);

 IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = results.Cast<ContactPersonViewModel>();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be `Select` method:

```
IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = results.Select(x => new ContactPersonViewModel 
{
   Id = x.Id
   //...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may helps (you can use the `Select` method):

```
  IEnumerable<ContactPersonViewModel> contactPersons = 
      results.Select(i=>new ContactPersonViewModel(){/*set your parameters */});
```

Don't forget to add the `using System.Linq;`